# VBA - Find ColumnLetter - Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

The goal is to find a certain string in an entire row (this is always Row 1). Identify the cell containing the string. Find the Column Letter of this cell (instead of the column number).

I have the function that takes Column letter from Range which I 'stole' from another page on Stackoverflow:

```
Function FnColFromRange(rInput As Range) As String
    FnColFromRange = Split(rInput.Address, "$")(1)
End Function
```

And then I have a sub to store the Column letter into a string called "colLetter"

```
Dim colLetter As String
With Workbooks("Wb.xlsx").Worksheets("Ws")
    Set myStringCell = .Rows(1).Find(myString)
    colLetter = FnColFromRange(myStringCell.Address)
End With
```

But it is always stuck on the "colLetter" line, saying Type Mismatch

Comment: Just do `colLetter = FnColFromRange(myStringCell)`, since your function is expecting a `Range`. I believe doing `myStringCell.Address` returns a `String`.

Comment: What do you need the column letter for? Excel will just convert it back to a number anyway...  You should probably be getting an error 1004 though - you never check to see if you got a `Range` back from `Find`.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thank you Bruce, This works!

Comment: @Comintern unfortunately a lot of formulas in my excel spreadsheet are referencing ColumnLetters in their formulas. I need to retrieve the columnletters using VBA and then apply those into Excel formulas...

Comment: Huh? Just get the appropriate Range for the formula and use its `.Address`...

Comment: @Comintern you must be talking about something much beyond me. I have an excel tab full of formulas such as SUMIF(Range, Criteria, AB:AB) where AB:AB represents an entire column. Every week, I have to replace AB:AB to AC:AC or maybe AE:AE.  The VBA is meant to pull the correct Column Letters.  Are you suggesting an alternative method that is much easier? If so, that'd be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check whether there is a real range returned from the `.Find()` method. Then, as @BruceWayne commented, probably the error is in the `myStringCell.Address`:

```
Dim colLetter As String
With Workbooks("Wb.xlsx").Worksheets("Ws")
    If Not .Rows(1).Find(myString) Is Nothing Then
        Set myStringCell = .Rows(1).Find(myString)
        colLetter = FnColFromRange(myStringCell)
    Else
        MsgBox "BOO!"
    End If
End With
```

However, something like this makes the function needless, as the `myStringCell` has a property named `.Column` and you may refer to it or use a 1 liner instead of the function:

```
Dim colLetter As String
With Workbooks("Wb.xlsx").Worksheets("Ws")
    If Not .Rows(1).Find(myString) Is Nothing Then
        Set myStringCell = .Rows(1).Find(myString)
        colLetter = Split(myStringCell.Address, "$")(1)
        Debug.Print myStringCell.Column 'if you can use the numeric column
    Else
        MsgBox "BOO!"
    End If
End With
```